# No enviar un input text de un formulario

Tags: html, jquery, twig

Necesito de todo el formulario que un input text no se me envié al servidor, hay alguna forma de realizarlo?, el input text tiene que estar presente para visualizarlo pero no recibirlo el servidor.

Gracias.

Comment: y tu codigo?, como lo estas enviando actualmente?, que has realizado hasta el momento?. Lee [ask] y [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que tienes un formulario parecido. Nota que el campo nombres tiene el atributo "**disabled**". Ese atributo hace que no se envíe al servidor (por lo menos con php, tienes que comprobarlo con el lenguaje que uses).
Pueden haber otras formas, pero en un form, sale muy práctico. Claro que aquí falta mucho (validaciones, el procesar.php).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <h2>Formulario HTML</h2>

    <form action="/accion.php">
        <label for="fname">Nombres:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="nombres" name="nombres" value="Fulano" disabled> 
        <br>
        <label for="lname">Apellidos:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" value="De Tal"><br> 
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <p>Si hace clic en el botón "Enviar", los datos del formulario se enviarán a una página llamada "/tuprocesar.php".</p>

</body>

</html>
```